# How do I shapeshift into a scientist or military personnel?

Tags: prototype-2

In Prototype 2 (PS3), how do I shapeshfit into military personnel or a scientist to access the Blacknet Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To shapeshift into a disguise, first you must consume the appropriate personnel.**

Close to the Blacknet Terminals, you will find military and scientists walking around. Walk up behind one, and when you aren't being watched, you will have the option to consume them. They are fairly easy to spot, due to their distinct uniforms and costumes.

You always have the ability to disguise, however, **you can only shapeshift into the last person you consumed**.